# count for different column in union and displaying in same row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I am trying to get a `count(*)` for different column from a different table using `union`.

```
//tbl_churidar

order_id    order_no_first    order_no
--------------------------------------
    1             C             1000
    2             C             1001
    3             C             1002

//tbl_anarkali

order_id    order_no_first    order_no
--------------------------------------
    1             A             1003
    2             A             1004
    3             A             1005

//tbl_assign

assign_id    order_id    order_no_first
---------------------------------------
   1            1              C
   2            1              A
   3            2              C
   4            3              C
   5            2              A
   6            3              A

//tbl_unit_status

status_id    assign_id    status_status    stitching_worker
-----------------------------------------------------------
    1           1            Stitch             AA
    2           2              QC             {null}
    3           3            Stitch             BB
    4           4            Stitch             BB
    5           5            Stitch             AA
    6           6            Stitch             CC
```

from the table `tbl_unit_status` where `status_status = Stitch` should `INNER JOIN` with other two table and get the total count of `churidar` and `anarkali` each `stitching_worker` taken.

the required output is,

```
churidar    anarkali    stitching_worker
----------------------------------------
   1           1             AA
   2           0             BB
   0           1             CC
```

I have tried to get the above output but got stuck. Below is my code,

```
SELECT churidar, anarkali, stitching_worker 
   FROM ((
          SELECT count(*) AS churidar, NULL AS anarkali, 
             us.stitching_worker 
          FROM tbl_unit_status us 
          INNER JOIN tbl_assign a ON a.assign_id = us.assign_id 
          INNER JOIN tbl_churidar o ON 
                (o.order_id = a.order_id AND 
                    o.order_no_first = a.order_no_first) 
          INNER JOIN tbl_contacts c ON c.contacts_id = o.contacts_id 
          LEFT JOIN tbl_title t ON t.title_id = c.title_id 
          WHERE us.status_status = "Stitch" AND 
                   o.order_no_first = "C" 
          GROUP BY us.stitching_worker
         ) 
        UNION (
           SELECT NULL AS churidar, count(*) AS anarkali,
                     us.stitching_worker 
           FROM tbl_unit_status us 
           INNER JOIN tbl_assign a ON a.assign_id = us.assign_id 
           INNER JOIN tbl_anarkali o ON (
                       o.order_id = a.order_id AND 
                         o.order_no_first = a.order_no_first) 
           INNER JOIN tbl_contacts c ON c.contacts_id = o.contacts_id  
           LEFT JOIN tbl_title t ON t.title_id = c.title_id 
           WHERE us.status_status = "Stitch" AND 
              o.order_no_first = "A" 
           GROUP BY us.stitching_worker
          )
         ) AS T1
```

the output for the above code is,

```
churidar    anarkali    stitching_worker
----------------------------------------
   1           0             AA
 {null}        1             AA
   2           0             BB
   0           1             CC
```

how to get the required output. I have tried a lot. Help me find the answer. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly (which I may not), you don't need the first two tables.  You can get the information you need from `tbl_assign` and just use aggregation:

```
select us.stitching_working,
       sum(a.order_no_first = 'C') as churidar,
       sum(a.order_no_first = 'A') as anarkali
from tbl_unit_status us join
     tbl_assign a
     on us.assign_id = a.assign_id 
where us.status_status = 'Stitch'
group by us.stitching_working;
```

Comment: I will give a try.